# continuous logging to database - fix errors

Tags: python, sqlite

So I have a python module that receives data and uploads it to a database.
I have a table health check that checks if the table is present, if number of columns is what it should be, also the types and names of columns.

So I have a bit of code like that:

```
def log_msg(message):
        try:
            insert(message)
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            table_health()
            log_msg(message)
```

`table_health()` drops the table if there's anything wrong with it and creates a new one.

I want the module to be able to fix the database, since data will be reported continuously. That's why I don't want to raise an exception, I've decided to handle it like that.

I also don't want to check health before executing the query, because this health check is performed at module import, so table should be ok prior to execution. The only problem arises if the table is dropped/changed during runtime. But most of the time table should be fine, so checking before every query seems like a waste - hence check on error.

Only solution to a possible infinite recursion I can see is to make sure log_msg is executed after an exception only once. By replacing it with `insert(message)`
Since if the table is going to be fixed, it's after one execution. Otherwise there's something wrong

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the method suggested in the last paragraph. Reasons are:

- Ensures that only one attempt is made to fix the table
- Only one retry of the failed method
- If an exception is caught and the table is to be fixed - it is really fixed after just one execution. If not - there's something wrong somewhere else

So I save the function to be called and the if there's an exception, I call it, rather than the wrapper function:

```
def log_msg(message):
    call_insert = None
    args_insert = ()
    try:
        #Save the function in the variable
        #in the real code there is a number of different insert() calls
        call_insert = insert
        args_insert = message
        insert(message)
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        if fix_table:
            table_health()
            call_insert(*args)
        else:
            raise
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to `log_msg` which indicates whether an attempt should be made to fix the table. If set to false, you raise the exception instead:

```
def log_msg(message, fix_table=True):
    try:
        insert(message)
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        if fix_table:
            table_health()
            log_msg(message, False)
        else:
            raise
```

Why are you actually facing the problem of of a corrupt table? This sounds very suspicious! Also, are you running in a multi-threaded, multi-process environment? Changing the table dynamically will cause problems if you don't pay attention to proper locking.

Comment: @Bernard I'd still rather replace log_msg(message) with insert(message)

Comment: @Bernard single process, single thread, so no problem there. I am not facing the problem, this is just a precautionary measure